# Как применить aggrerated function к уже ранее примененной aggragated function?

Tags: sql, bigquery

У меня есть простой запрос:

```
SELECT  
device_id,
COUNT(md_5)
FROM email
GROUP BY device_id
ORDER BY COUNT(md_5) ASC
```

Как видите, он группирует все данные по `device_id` и считает количество `md_5` по уникальному `device_id`
Теперь, я хочу получить `MEAN` или `AVG` по столбцу `COUNT(md_5)`. 
Как это сделать? 
Т. е., мне надо применить aggregated function к ранее созданной aggregated function.

Comment: Почему просто не сделать подзапрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Среднее по количеству всех девайсов.

```
   SELECT
      AVG(cnt)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        device_id, 
        COUNT(md_5) cnt
    FROM email 
    GROUP BY device_id)
```